# What does $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ actually mean?

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

We all know what $\mathbb{R}^n$ means. But I came across this statement about $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in a note that says $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is a vector space under pointwise operations has no natural norm. The note provides no further explanation about it.

My questions are:
1. What is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$? How do we call it? Is it a Euclidean vector space?
2. What does pointwise operations mean? And why does it not have a natural norm?

I tried to google $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ but did not seem to find a good explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: Pointwise operations is the easiest to explain.  It just means that vector addition and scalar multiplication are performed entry-by-entry, where we think of the elements of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ as sequences of real numbers.

Comment: The reason that the notation $A^B$ is used for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}$, where $|X|$ means the number of elements in $X$. (This makes the most sense for finite sets, but one can define things in such a way that it makes sense for infinite sets, too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, $A^B=\{f\colon B\to A\}$ is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. So, $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of functions $f\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$. Since a function $f\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ is essentially the same as a sequence $(a_n)$, we call $\mathbb R ^{\mathbb N}$ the set of sequences in $\mathbb R$. It is not a Euclidean vector space.

By pointwise operation we mean that we define the structure by restricting attention to each coordinate separately. E.g., $\alpha \cdot (a_n)=(\alpha \cdot a_n)$. The fact that this gives rise to a vector space is a triviality that you should verify to yourself. Finally, the lack of a natural norm is the (somewhat vague and imprecise) statement that the standard norm on $\mathbb R^n$, namely $\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_k^nu_kv_k $ does not extend to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, since it requires replacing $n$ by $\infty $, but there is no reason for the series to converge in general.

Comment: Just a nitpick: $\langle u,v\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^nu_kv_k$ is the standard _inner product_ on $\mathbb R^n$. The standard _norm_ is $||u|| = \langle u,u\rangle^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ is the set of all real sequences. It is a vector space where we define $(a_n)+(b_n)=(a_n+b_n)$ and $\alpha\cdot (a_n)=(\alpha a_n)$ for sequences $(a_n),(b_n)\in\mathbb R^\mathbb N, \alpha\in \mathbb R$ .
2. It does not have a "natural" norm of the sort that $\mathbb R^n$ has since $\sum a_n^2$ need not be convergent for any sequence $(a_n)$.

You can replace $\mathbb R$ with any field here to get a vector space.

Comment: Thanks @Shahab. Are you saying the sequences as infinite sequences?

Comment: @user71346: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

$A^B$ is the set of functions from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: True, but there is much more to the question here.  Specifically it is asked how $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is a vector space, and whether is has a natural{?} norm.